# "Afterware" for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with middlewares right now, and my concern right now is:

Middlewares can run before the controllers, but is it possible to run a middleware before a controller gives a response to the user?

I would like to set some headers after controller was executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, a middleware can be used to modify **request and response.**

Here is the basic structure of a Middleware commented:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SomeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // Here, you can perform action before passing it to the controllers

        $response = $next($request);

        // Here, you get back the response generated by the controllers 
        // and you can add cookies or anything you want

        return $response;
    }
}
```

As you can see, using `$response = $next($request);` is like the separator of what you want to do before and after passing the request to the controller.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me... I will try it now :)

Comment: If you check out the Laracasts introduction to Middleware, Jeffrey describes Middleware like an onion, where the request has to walk through the outer layers to get to the center, and then again on the way out. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/16

Answer (score 0):

[El_Matella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4547701/el-matella) is right you can use AfterMiddleware

**Controller**

```
public function headers( Request $request  )
{
    return  response('Hello World', 200)
                    ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
}
```

**MiddleWare**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform action
        $header =  $response->headers->all();
        dd($header);


        return $response;
    }
}
```

You can even set the header in MiddleWare.